# Call a Javascript/Ajax function only when user are done with changes for multi-select input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a muti-select dropdown in the form and I want to make an Ajax call to get the data based on the selected values from the backend and display the related information.

```js
const getValues = (select) =>
  Array.from(select.selectedOptions, ({ value }) => value);

document
  .getElementById("locations")
  .addEventListener("change", ({ target }) => {
    const values = getValues(target);
    console.log("change", values);

    // make Ajax call...
  });
```

```html
<select id="locations" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">United States of America</option>
   <option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
   <option value="5">France</option>
</select>
```

[image: Multi-select picker]

I can not use the `onchange` event on the `<select>` element as it calls the js function as soon as the user changes the selected option. What event listener can I add on the `select` element so it makes the Ajax call only when the user is done with selecting the item?

Appreciate for any help. Thank you.

Comment: When is the user done? You can add debouncing, but better would be a button saying "I'm done"

Comment: The _blur_ event seems the logical option but it does require the focus to move to another element before triggering

Comment: @mplungjan I understand OP's issue. The change event fires for every selection (eg when using Ctrl+Click / Shift+Click). I agree with using a button to indicate completion

Comment: @Phil I also understood. I was asking OP if THEY knew when the user was done. Perhaps they are old or have to think  - if it is a timed quiz, then a delayed submit instead of a debounce could make more sense

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for the suggestions, the application has external js libraries to gather user activities analytics, so I suspect adding debounce would not be an ideal approach? I would instead consider adding a new button "Done" if there is no appropriate event that I am looking for.

Comment: @Phil, thanks for the suggestion, I will try adding a `blur` event and see if it works with the current UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [debouncing](https://www.google.com/search?q=debouncing), but better would be a button saying "I'm done"

Here is however a debounced select with a 1 second delay - when the user stops changing the select for 1 second the action triggers.

For a timed quiz, you could simply trigger the ajax after the allotted time

```js
const sel = document.getElementById("select1");
const debounce = (func, delay) => { // function to call after delay ms
  let debounceTimer;
  return (...args) => { // arguments passed to the function
    clearTimeout(debounceTimer); // user was not done yet.
    debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => func(...args), delay); // call with aguments after delay
  };
};

const handleSelectChange = () => {
  const selectedValues = [...sel.selectedOptions]
                            .map(option => option.value);
  console.log("Selected Values:", selectedValues); // Replace this with your AJAX call logic
  // Implement AJAX logic here
};

sel.addEventListener('change', debounce(handleSelectChange, 1000)); // 1000 ms (1 seccond) delay
```

```html
<select id="select1" multiple>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">One</option>
<option value="3">One</option>
<option value="4">One</option>
<option value="5">One</option>
```